# Staircase Shadows / Shadows look like faces

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

right now I am rendering a scene with an environment map and some point lights in Blender 2.79. 
I just noticed that a part of my bowl has some weird "staircase shadow".

The mesh should be high poly enough and it is also set to smooth.

[image]

Comment: i guess there is something wrong with your shader, maybe with the bump/displacement. You could re-rendern the image with a default diffuse shader, without any displacement and see, if the artifacts are still there. if they are still there, make sure your mesh has "smooth shading" activated. if it is gone, you know that the problem is within the shader.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will try that as soon as my render is finished.

Answer (score 1):

The artefacts are rendered due to low subdivision. I reproduced them on a poorly subdevided sphere. Just add another level of subdivision and you should be good to go.

[image]