# How can I make the Bishop's hat in the chess piece?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, bevel, polycount

I have attached a blender file below along with some pictures. I tried to use the boolean modifier to do the same but came up with rather difficult to work with results. I want to have the curve and the shape of the hat to be nearly the same as the real Staunton Bishop.[image: First]

[image: Second]

gdrive link to blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x1poqr1abMpW_miAbRIkWpvRVR0twlMc

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89990/smooth-shading-creates-odd-shading https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104910/cutting-into-cylinder?r=SearchResults&s=3|33.6324

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First close the top of the mesh, then put the *Boolean* modifier above the *Subdivision Surface* and use a shape like this one and it seems to work fine.  When you're glad apply the modifier and bring some corrections so that the mesh is clean: Quads instead of ngons, bevels to sharp the edges, etc...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: Tried it and it works! just requires a lot of finishing afterwards